# Break UL tag after 'n' times in while-loop

Tags: php

I'm currently in developing module shop for the company I work for and there is a little problem. While extracting records from the table, I want for every third data record to close HTML "UL" tag.

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php
  $selektKat = "SELECT * FROM `proizvodi` WHERE `kategorija` = '$kat'"; //don't worry about SQLi; I will fix it
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $selektKat) or die(mysqli_error());

// Line where the loop starts
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

  <ul class="products-grid clearfix" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">
  <li class="item" style="min-height: 339px">
    <a id="product-image-42321" href="proizvod.php" title="naziv" class="product-image">
      <img src="http://static.511tactical.com/mag/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/220x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/3/53212_716_Alternate1.jpg" width="220" alt="<?php echo $row['naziv'] ?>" />
    </a>
      <ul class="swatches clearfix">
      <li id="swatch-228" class="swatch product-42321">
        <a href="proizvod.php" title="<?php echo $row['naziv']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/images/' . $row['slika'] . '.jpg'; ?>" />
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="price-box">
        <span class="label" id="configurable-price-from-42321">
          <span class="configurable-price-from-label">
          </span>
        </span>


      <div class="product-name"><a id="product-name-140981" href="proizvod.php"><?php echo $row['naziv']; ?></a></div>

      <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-42321">
        <span class="price"><?php echo $row['cijena']; ?><sup>KM</sup>
        </span>
      </span>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
      </div>

  </li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul> // This has to be closed in loop after every 3 records
</div>
```

Picture:
[image]

Cheers.

Comment: `if($count % 3 == 0){ //close ul}`

Comment: I would be gladly interested in reasonable explanation from someone who gave -1 to my question. The questions is correct by all SO standards. Thanks in advance. @Brotheyura I didn't think of that, smart way. You should answer the question by the way.

Comment: See my answer it really easy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I provide simple PHP script that can be addapted to your needs. In this script open and end tags are handled properly.

I added also `$break_after` variable - you can set here any positive value you want - in your case it's 3 because you want to do the action after each 3rd element.

**First method (it assumes you can get number of data elements before loop)**

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$break_after = 3;

$counter = 0;   
$totalNumber = count($data);                    
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($counter % $break_after == 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';    

    if ($counter % $break_after == ($break_after-1) || $counter == $totalNumber-1) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ++$counter;

}
```

**Second method (it assumes you cannot get number of data elements before loop)**

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$break_after = 3;

$counter = 0;               
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($counter % $break_after == 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';    

    if ($counter % $break_after == ($break_after-1)) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ++$counter;

}

if ((($counter-1) % $break_after) != ($break_after-1)) {
    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Regarding your question, you also need to remember to start your `<ul>` each 3rd record (not just closing it) but also make sure to close it after your loop. In your case you can use **second method** because you don't know number of elements (in fact you can get them using `mysqli_num_rows` function and then you could also use method 1). For your case your code should probably look like this:

```
<?php
  $selektKat = "SELECT * FROM `proizvodi` WHERE `kategorija` = '$kat'"; //don't worry about SQLi; I will fix it
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $selektKat) or die(mysqli_error());

// Line where the loop starts
<?php
$counter = 0;   

$break_after = 3;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  if ($counter % $break_after == 0) {
   ?>
  <ul class="products-grid clearfix" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 20px;">
  <?php } ?>
  <li class="item" style="min-height: 339px">
    <a id="product-image-42321" href="proizvod.php" title="naziv" class="product-image">
      <img src="http://static.511tactical.com/mag/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/220x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/5/3/53212_716_Alternate1.jpg" width="220" alt="<?php echo $row['naziv'] ?>" />
    </a>
      <ul class="swatches clearfix">
      <li id="swatch-228" class="swatch product-42321">
        <a href="proizvod.php" title="<?php echo $row['naziv']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/images/' . $row['slika'] . '.jpg'; ?>" />
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="price-box">
        <span class="label" id="configurable-price-from-42321">
          <span class="configurable-price-from-label">
          </span>
        </span>


      <div class="product-name"><a id="product-name-140981" href="proizvod.php"><?php echo $row['naziv']; ?></a></div>

      <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-42321">
        <span class="price"><?php echo $row['cijena']; ?><sup>KM</sup>
        </span>
      </span>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
      </div>

  </li>

<?php
    if ($counter % $break_after == ($break_after - 1)) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    ++$counter;

}

if (($counter-1) % $break_after != ($break_after - 1)) { // make sure there will be closing </ul>
    echo '</ul>';

}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually the only correct answer, as it accounts for opening the `<ul>` tags and takes care of the last closing `<ul>` in case the amount of data is not divisible with 3

Comment: as this is a very common problem I'd suggest to keep your answer as clean and clear as possible for future reference. The example code of the poster - although correct - does not add up to clearity. And as the implementation is easy as pie with only the simple example, would it be a good idea to remove the posters example? Just a thought...

Comment: @giorgio not to be pedantic, but my answer does that too.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Almost :) because when the amount of items in your data is divisible by three, you end up with an empty `<ul></ul>` in the end. That is not desirable behavior.

Comment: @giorgio you are right. I deleted my answer. This is not the way I myself would do it anyway ;-)).

Comment: @BartFriederichs Well, in that case: post an answer with your own solution! :) That might actually be very helpful, and it is always a good thing to have multiple distinct but correct solutions, as every individual solution tends to have it's pros and cons.

Comment: @giorgio Thank you for advice. I've added more info  for this answer

Comment: @giorgio, my solution would entail a completely different design using templates or frameworks.

Comment: @BartFriederichs IMO that has nothing to do with the problem at hand... the logic of the problem/solution will be the same, wether you use a php-loop or a template-loop or whatever...

Comment: @giorgio with "different design" I also mean I wouldn't use a `<li>` for this HTML design, but `<div>` that are styled in columns (or something like that).

Comment: Hello Marcin, your answer is accepted as it perfectly shows the way which I can implement the function. I read through the comments and saw many great advices from @giorgio. Let the code from my example be in your answer, it may help others to finalize their needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Our images
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
//Count array for last ul
$count_array = count($array);
//Counter
$count       = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $count++;
    //Begin
    if ($count % 3 == 1) {
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    //Output data
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    //Close ul
    if ($count % 3 == 0 || $count_array == $count) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul><ul><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul><ul><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li></ul><ul><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul><ul><li>13</li><li>14</li></ul>
```

- 1
- 2
- 3

- 4
- 5
- 6

- 7
- 8
- 9

- 10
- 11
- 12

- 13
- 14

Comment: Easy and function well. Keep it up, I'm not sure who downvoted you but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically ask for opening and closing `<ul>` tags, but may I suggest an alternative, using only css, which can be easily converted into a responsive solution?

To start with, just put your items in a div instead of an list item (omitting the `<ul>` altogether):

```
<div class="product-grid">
    <?php while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ): ?>
        <div class="item"> ... </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Now just use plain old css to float the grid and add margins in between the columns. Then using the `nth-of-type` pseudo-selector we can clear the margin on the `nth` element, depending on how many items you want in a row.

**Always-3-column-grid example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxW5J/2/))**

```
.product-grid { width: 100%; }
.product-grid .item { float: left; width: 32%; margin-left: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%; }
.product-grid .item:nth-of-type(3n+1) { margin-left: 0; }
```

Now the items are placed nicely in a grid, and it doesn't matter at all how wide the container is.

Fiddle note: the `overflow: hidden` is a kind of clearfix to show the border. It also works without it.

Now if you want, for instance, add breakpoints to show a 2-column grid instead of a 3-column grid on smaller devices, just change the width of the item and the counter of the pseudo selector. I've put the 3-grid counter in a media query as well, so you don't have to overwrite that one.

**3-to-2-column-grid example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxW5J/3/))**

Don't forget to resize the example panel to see the responsive result ;)

```
.product-grid { width: 100%; }
.product-grid .item { float: left; width: 32%; margin-left: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%; }

/* 3-column */
@media (min-width: 501px) {
    .product-grid .item:nth-of-type(3n+1) { margin-left: 0; }
}

/* 2-column. Don't forget to alter the item width accordingly */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .product-grid .item { width: 49%; }
    .product-grid .item:nth-of-type(2n+1) { margin-left: 0; }
}
```

And here you go! Your fully responsive 3-to-2-column grid :) Just alter the breakpoints to your needs, and the width and margin sizes (just to make sure that in a 3-column version `3*columnWidth + 2*marginWidth` adds up to 100%, and `2*columnWidth + marginWidth` for the 2-column version).

Comment: Hello @giorgio, your answer is great, but depends on the needs responsive is added. I tried to implement your logic code and it worked with out problems, though my styling-sheet is already responsive. Take an upvote for great answer! :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

// Your code

if($i % 5 == 0){ // Break </ul> tag here}

// Rest of code


$i++;
} // End while loop
```

the `%` is [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), it returns the remainder after a division is done, so

`5 % 5 = 0`
`9 % 5 = 4`

Comment: Check @Marcin answer, it's much longer and explain situation well. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score -2):

Add a `varaible`, let's say `$i` in you while that you increment at each iteration.
And when it is a **multiple of 3**, just close your `ul`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // YOUR CODE HERE

    $count++;
    if ($count % 3 == 0) echo '</ul>';
}
```

For the record the `%`operator will give you the remainder of the euclidean division.