# Smarty new table row every nth time

Tags: php, iteration, smarty

Hi I'm making this HTML email and thanks to the good old Outlook 07 that adds a really nice page break I kinda have to change my logic. Currently my html looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>  //I want for every 6th element to create a new <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        {foreach from=$data.elements item=element name=elements}
        {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}
        <tr>
          <td>
        {/if}
            <table align="{if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}left{else}right{/if}">
                Some content
            </table>
          {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}
            <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tr>
                  <td width="100%" height="40" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          {else}
                  </td>
               </tr>
          {/if}
          {/foreach}
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Right now after the 6th element it creates this page break so I want is when I have let's say 12 elements each six to have their own table row with table inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
<table>

        {foreach from=$data.elements item=element name=elements}
        {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration mod 6 eq 1}
            <tr>  
            <td>
                <table>
        {/if}        

        {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}
        <tr>
          <td>
        {/if}
            <table align="{if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}left{else}right{/if}">
                Some content
            </table>
          {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration is odd}
            <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tr>
                  <td width="100%" height="40" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          {else}
                  </td>
               </tr>
          {/if}
          {if $smarty.foreach.elements.iteration mod 6 eq 0 or $smarty.foreach.elements.last}
               </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {/if}          
          {/foreach}

</table>
```

but because of many tables I cannot check it for sure. You could also look at [Break UL tag after 'n' times in while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24774946/3593996)  where I answered how to do the same in PHP.